# Assign variables with operator inside lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm working with pandas. I have an existing column with accumulated days starting in the second day, ex -> `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..]`. I'm trying to create a new Dataframe with the count of the week. I want to use lambda for this but I'm not able to figure out how to do this.
The code looks like this

```
day_counter = 1
week = 1
df_eqpt['WeekNumber'] = df_eqpt['day'].apply(lambda x: week + 1 if day_counter == day_counter + 7 else day_counter += 1)
```

Any suggestions of how to go about this are much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). That is, the question in the title is tangential to the problem you're actually trying to solve, and I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it, like using slicing for example. You might want to [edit] and make the title about the actual problem. It'd also help to provide a [mre] including a sample of `df_eqpt` and your desired output. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, for overall tips, check out [ask].

Comment: Can you add an input dataframe and excepted results?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output?

Comment: I think I figured out a way to do it using floor division, but I want to make sure I understand what you want first.

Comment: The root of your problem is `day_counter == day_counter + 7` which is never going to be true.  Did you mean `day_counter == 7`??

Answer (score 0):

1. You say you want to implement with a lambda,
   but it's not working.
   Keep it simple and self explanatory:
   `def` a named function rather than writing an anonymous lambda.
2. Scope of local variables within a function isn't doing you any favors.
   You might choose to use the `global` keyword,
   but it's probably better to create a new `class Counter:` and
   maintain state in `self.day_count` and `self.week`.
3. You might find it simpler to define `start`
   as a convenient type such as `datetime`,
   and then increment a `timedelta`.
4. Consider tacking on an extra column that has
   a sequential integer, or maybe the df index already offers that.
   Then, instead of needing `.apply( ... )`,
   you could do a much simpler assignment of an expression.
5. Perhaps the [`.isocalendar()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isocalendar) function would prove handy.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects